# Add ListBox items from Dataset

Tags: asp.net, listbox, dataset, loops, for-loop

I have this C# code.

```
j = myAccountDataset.Tables["AccountsTables"].Rows.Count;

                for (i = 0; i <= (j - 1); i++ )
                {

                   listAccountList.Items.Add(myAccountDataset.Tables[0].Rows[i][1]);
                }

                this.listAccountList.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

the idea is to iterate inside the dataset and add the items to the list.
but i am getting the following errors:
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection.Add(string)' has some invalid arguments

Argument1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

i must be doing something wrong. thye error is in the line:   listAccountList.Items.Add(myAccountDataset.Tables[0].Rows[i][1]);

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ListItemCollection's Add method only accepts two types - a string or a ListItem
See the MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.add.aspx). You need to pass a string instead of an object:

```
listAccountList.Items.Add(myAccountDataset.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

A little more description

Your myAccountDataset.Tables[0].Rows[i][1] is a typeless object, the Add method is expecting a string, you will need to cast the object to a string. The simplest method of doing this is to add the .ToString() operator to your datarow object

```
myAccountDataset.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].Tostring()
```